# Classify the group of functions by applying Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated Abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Suppose $F^F$ be the set of functions mapping from any field $F$ to $F$; i.e.,

$$F^F = \{ \alpha \mid \alpha : F \rightarrow F \}$$

How can I classify the groups $(\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{\mathbb{Z}_{2}},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{\mathbb{Z}_{3}},+)$ into their direct sums?

I still don't know how to find the rank of each.

The only thing I know is that

$$(\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{\mathbb{Z}_{2}},+) = \{ \{ (0,0),(1,0) \} , \{ (0,0),(1,1) \}, \{ (0,1),(1,0) \} , \{ (0,1),(1,1) \} \}$$.

Please help!

Comment: $G^H=\{\alpha:H\to G\}$ is literally $\prod_{h\in H}G$ which is equal to direct sum when $H$ is finite. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\mathbb{Z}_2}$ is almost literally $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$. Analogously $\mathbb{Z}_3^{\mathbb{Z}_3}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: You haven't told us what $F$ is.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, F is a field. I've already edited. Thank you.